# What exactly happens to create a user by "useradd -ms `which false`"?

Tags: users, login

I'm watching a video where the author says we can use this command in order to keep the user from logging in.

```
useradd -ms `which false` u2
```

Below is my testing.

```
[root@192 ~]# tree -dL 1 /home
/home
├── u1
└── user1

2 directories
[root@192 ~]# useradd -ms `which false` u2
[root@192 ~]# tree -dL 1 /home
/home
├── u1
├── u2
└── user1

3 directories
[root@192 ~]# passwd u2
Changing password for user u2.
New password: 
BAD PASSWORD: The password is shorter than 8 characters
Retype new password: 
passwd: all authentication tokens updated successfully.
[root@192 ~]# logout
[u1@192 ~]$ whoami
u1
[u1@192 ~]$ logout
[user1@192 ~]$ whoami
user1
[user1@192 ~]$ su - u2
Password: 
[user1@192 ~]$ whoami
user1
[user1@192 ~]$ su - u2
Password: 
Last login: Tue Apr 19 11:22:01 PDT 2022 on pts/0
[user1@192 ~]$ whoami
user1
[user1@192 ~]$
```

To me, I feel like the user can log in successfully, since there is no errors. And, as you can see, when I try to log in again, it even tells me my last login time. It's just the user got disconnected as soon as he connects. Is this true? What exactly happens underneath?

Comment: double or triple backquotes seem to work, or just using a code block

Comment: Every user has a default shell, which is what program runs when they log in. A typical user would have their shell as `bash` or `zsh`, i.e., a command line interface from which you run other commands. `false` is a special program that immediately exits with an error. If you set your shell to `false`, then when you log in, your session will immediately end, and you won't have a way to execute any commands. But you are still logging in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-s` option to `useradd` ([man page](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/passwd/useradd.8.en.html)) is:

> `-s`, `--shell SHELL`
> The name of the user's login shell.

And `` `which false` `` just gives the path to the command `false`, which does nothing but exit (with an error, but that doesn't matter).

So, for the most part, the user works normally, just that they have a shell that doesn't run, so they can't actually do anything.

You should probably *not* create a password for them, and instead use something like `usermod -L u2` ([man page](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/passwd/usermod.8.en.html)) to lock the account password, or `chage` ([man page](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/passwd/chage.1.en.html)) to make the account expired, depending a bit on what you want to do with it.

(Locking the password in `/etc/shadow`, or having the account expired does exactly nothing as far as the kernel is concerned. Just the various tools and libraries related to logging in etc. look at that stuff.)